# DigitalOcean Spaces + Refile isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, digital-ocean

I'm trying to integrate Spaces using **refile/s3** because I thought it would be the best approach to integrate Spaces easiest. But I'm running into some errors. The first error is the following:

```
Aws::Errors::NoSuchEndpointError (Encountered a `SocketError` while attempting to connect to: 
  https://bluebird-docs-feature.s3.nyc3.amazonaws.com/cache/5057974609d11435f333e99b1f2896dae159fd4c978a2710a945caedb2e3
```

Here is my **config/initializers/refile.rb** file:

```
require "refile/s3"

aws = {
  access_key_id: Rails.application.secrets.digitalocean_spaces_key,
  secret_access_key: Rails.application.secrets.digitalocean_spaces_secret,
  region: "nyc3",
  bucket: Rails.application.secrets.digitalocean_spaces_bucket
      }

  Refile.cache = Refile::S3.new(prefix: "cache", **aws)
  Refile.store = Refile::S3.new(prefix: "store", **aws)
```

My **secrets.yml** file:

```
digitalocean_spaces_key: XYZ
digitalocean_spaces_secret: XYZ
digitalocean_spaces_bucket: XYZ
```

I have these gems included for refile:

```
gem "refile-s3"
gem 'refile', github: 'refile/refile', require: 'refile/rails'
gem 'refile-mini_magick', github: 'refile/refile-mini_magick'
gem 'sinatra', github: 'sinatra/sinatra', branch: 'master'
```

I don't have any other AWS or DigitalOcean gems installed.

Thank you ahead of time. If you need more info just ask!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Refile or DigitalOcean Spaces but it's indicative that if you're trying to use Spaces, your endpoint shouldn't be hitting AWS (amazonaws.com), which is why you're seeing the `Aws::Errors::NoSuchEndpointError`. There's probably a configuration method to specify the proper host if DigitalOcean Spaces is indeed an S3-compatible API.